# How to solve view folder problem in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes, ejs, render

I have the problem, that I specified the following lines:

```
app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

But I still get the following error's:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "index.ejs" in views directory "./views"
    at ...
```

Later in the code (after the two declaratons) have several routes calling the following function (sometimes it's another file, but the outcome is the same):

```
res.render('index.ejs', {r})
```

My problem is, that I can't figure out the problem with this, a couple of days ago, I had my scripts on my server (and everything worked), now I moved everything inside a VM on my server and it stoped working (I did not change the code).

Oh and btw changing the 1st parameter of the function from 'index.ejs' to 'index' does not affect it in any ways.

Comment: What is your directory structure like? From which directory do you start the app (what is the working directory, `$PWD`?)

Comment: The `app.js` lies in the root of the project, the `index.ejs` lies in the `views` folder which itself lies in the root of the project, the app is started via a service file that executes `node /nodejs/projectname/app.js`

Comment: Does it work if you change `'./views'` to `path.join(__dirname, './views')` where `const path = require('path')`?

Comment: it seems to work, the CSS is still broken, but at least I get HTML code delivered

Comment: Sounds like there could be a similar issue with `express.static()`.